# spring-security-shiro org.apache.shiro.authc.AccountException: Not logged in or anonymous

Tags: grails, shiro, grails3

I am in the process of migration my app from grails 2.4.4 to grails 3.2.9.

I am trying to migrate to

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-shiro:3.0.1'
```

When I try to sign in with a user I get the following error:

```
   org.apache.shiro.authc.AccountException: Not logged in or anonymous
            at grails.plugin.springsecurity.shiro.SpringSecurityRealm.getCurrentUser(SpringSecurityRealm.groovy:76)
            at grails.plugin.springsecurity.shiro.SpringSecurityRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(SpringSecurityRealm.groovy:95)
            at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
            at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
            at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
            at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
            at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$login.call(Unknown Source)
```

In my application rules I have:

```
[pattern: '/login/auth/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
```

In grails 2.4.4 I would be able to debug the dbRealm.groovy file but I cannot do that with the new plugin.

I know the user is not logged in as that is what I am trying to do but why might it think my user is anonymous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-shiro/v3/index.html#permissions

> This will transitively install the Spring Security Core plugin, so
>   you’ll need to configure that by running the s2-quickstart script.

so looking at https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/
and at https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.1.x/index.html (cause you're using Grails 3.2.x)

> 3.5. Anonymous authentication
>
> In standard Spring Security and older versions of the plugin, there is
>   support for an “anonymous” authentication. This is implemented by a
>   filter that registers a simple Authentication in the SecurityContext
>   to remove the need for null checks, since there will always be an
>   Authentication available. This approach is still problematic though
>   because the Principal of the anonymous authentication is a String,
>   whereas it is a UserDetails instance when there is a non-anonymous
>   authentication.
>
> Since you still have to be careful to differentiate between anonymous
>   and non-anonymous authentications, the plugin now creates an anonymous
>   Authentication which will be an instance of
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken
>   with a standard org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
>   instance as its Principal. The authentication will have a single
>   granted role, ROLE_ANONYMOUS.

and

> 5.2. URLs and Authorities
>
> In each approach you configure a mapping for a URL pattern to the
>   role(s) that are required to access those URLs, for example,
>   /admin/user/** requires ROLE_ADMIN. In addition, you can combine the
>   role(s) with SpEL expressions and/or tokens such as
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED, and
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY. One or more voters (Voters) will process any
>   tokens and enforce a rule based on them:
>
> ```
> IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
>
>     signifies that anyone can access this URL. By default the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter ensures an “anonymous” Authentication
> ```
>
> with no roles so that every user has an authentication. The token
>   accepts any authentication, even anonymous.
>
> ```
>     The SpEL expression permitAll is equivalent to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY and is typically more intuitive to use
> ```

Comment: thanks for the info and links (accepted the answer , I now know why it states my user is anonymous) . It seems like I am stuck in a catch 22; I either allow assess to the method and try to sign in which gets the error above. Or I set access to role_admin but then as I have yet to authenticate I get "permission denied"